# How to monitor energy usage in processor

Tags: energy

I'd like to monitor the energy consumption of cpu on a  server.
I've studied about IPMI and with it is possible monitor cpu directly at hardware.

I tested some software, like powertop, but I believe that they provide estimated values of the processor (through OS).

Does anyone know of any tools of energy usage (Linux)?

Comment: Your problem is, from what I understood, that you want **exact** power usage, rather than an estimate? Assuming you had access to the machine, you could try to install a power meter to the power plug, that would give you the total power the PC was using. It isn't reasonable to ask of a PC to be 100% aware of it's power usage, IMHO.

Comment: Why do you need more then an estimate?  You know the power requirements of the CPU you can calculate the maxium amount of power it will require in a 24 hour period of time allowing to you calculate the costs to run for a single day.  You can then project diferent power usages across larger amounts of time.  But there is more then the CPU using power at the end of the day, which cannot be monitored, which leads to only an estimate no matter what.